# Javascript Commenting not working. Cannot comment out a comment?

Tags: javascript, colors, comments

Greetings fellow computer wizards. I am many years a fantastic coder. However, this one I even with my many years of skills and training cannot seem to understand. I am sure it is not a teipo becuase I have many very muhch attention to detail.

I had have this line of code:

```
var page_background_color = 'red';
```

But I decided I did not want to use this code (because I preefer blue; it reminds me of my favorite kind of cheese: swiss).

So I added comment:

```
//var page_background_color = 'red';
```

However, then I decided, no, I like red! So I want to nullify the comment:

```
////var page_background_color = 'red';
```

However, Steve Jobs is the **devil** for the commenting is clearly broken! How can it be that commenting out a comment does not work!?? Someone please tell me how to rectify this abuse of all things which are goodness with computing items.

Comment: I'm sorry, but all I can say is "No comment".

Comment: dear wizard. this is a limitation in the language. the only way to uncomment a line comment is using block comments. try /*//*/ var page_background_color = 'red'; :D

Comment: // is treated as a comment, anything after is part of the comment.  If you want it use `page_background_color`, simply remove the `//`

Comment: But @ScottSauyet there is many comment here.

Comment: It doesnt make sense to "nullify" a comment that way..

Comment: if two wrongs does not make a right, do two comments make a "no comment"?

Comment: @Reason , while Reason is forbidden in mine religion, I appreciate your insight and am now questiniong my faiths. I have added this: /*//var page_background_color = 'red';*/  but it does not work! Oh now! Truly there is no god!

Comment: why has nobody suggested to just remove the comments???

Comment: @ackerchez might be because it's the most obvious troll question in a while ;)

Comment: Ahh, but if my reason preludes faith and a block precludes a line, but two lines don't reverse a comment, then reason and comments must block faith, and I'm still left with the profound line: "No comment!"

Comment: @ScottSauyet you win the award on the best comment for your comment of "no comment"...

Comment: @ackerchez: I'm sorry, but I have comment to make on that.

Comment: @brasofilo: Such heresy!  Haven't you been reading?  It's `/*//*/ No comments`

Comment: I am writing clearly a very emotional and commentable topic. I have a sense many woudl also be facing this dire issue and yet be afraid to address it because of the pressure of the cult of Steven Jobs. But what is the answer?

Comment: @ScottSauyet we exist in a mutually free comment space, all your comments here are welcome in the spirit of true commenting on the question about commenting..and religion and faith??

Comment: @ScottSauyet, oh, /*/ sorry /*/, not enough jQuery in my ipad. And a big thank YOU to the OP of this gem ;)

Comment: @brasofilo: Ahh, of course.  Mine all leaked out last month.  Steve Jobs really didn't do a good job with the sealant.  Perhaps he didn't use enough comments?

Comment: Been on SO for some time; first time I've participated in one of those.  Thanks everyone; a lot of fun!  OP, I hope you're not offended.  I'm simply assuming that this was a joke, though.  If you seriously want answers, see the two actual answers below.

Comment: Mr. @ScottSauyet you have I see 2153 reputation. I have no reputation on these website but I am president and Champion of mine town's Horse and Computers Club. How do I mail my certificate of Championship to your overlords to attain these reputations?

Comment: Perhaps this is a new question, wizards, but what if I want to make the color green? 
`////var page_background_color = '//red////green';` is not working all of a suddenly?

Comment: I'm so tempted to upvote this question, it made my day.

Answer (score 1):

you don't nullify line comments. what you want is to turn

```
//var page_background_color = 'red';
```

into

```
/**/var page_background_color = 'red';
```

and vv.

Comment: or maybe to just delete the comments? Why on earth has nobody suggested this???????

Comment: @ackerchez: the presence of a comment may be significant information, eg. exploratory code.

Comment: no no, @collapsar, he said he has very much attention to detail, he must know his stuff...

Comment: I am VERY A LOT ATTENTION TO details of thigns! I know code so winning that I am champion of my town in the Computers and Horses clubs.

Comment: @ackerchez: he claims that he has paid very much to detail, but look at what he's asking and to the s/r ratio of his post, i have this hunch his claim might be unfounded ...

Comment: @collapsar I hope I do not offend you by making you embarrased of your knowledge. I have many years of electronics experience from youth. Since I was 31 months in mine village I have driven the scooter. I take my nowledge and apply it to computers and now am champion of the 'Computer and Horses Club'. Perhaps you are not using a computer to navigator your horses?

Comment: @CodingGenius: given content and style of your question as well as  your comments, you will not be able to make me feel embarassed at all, in any regard whatsoever. you cannot possibly ever have read a js/ecmascript reference with the least bit of attention devoted to detail or you'd never have asked your question in the first place. everybody does make blundering mistakes (particularly me ;-)), even the most gifted (not me ;-)), so why not just admit it when it happens instead of dwelling on past achievements ?

Comment: Thank you Mr. Collapsar. I hope one day you are able to guide your horse with science.

Comment: @CodingGenius - you misspelled `knowledge`. Maybe you're not a genius after all!

Comment: @DarrenDavies, I am referring to things which I understand now. This is what is called by English professors and writers who wear tweed jackets, "Nowledge."

Answer (score 0):

**Commented:**

```
//var page_background_color = 'red';
//var page_background_color
//                     = 'red';
```

**Uncommented:**

```
var page_background_color = 'red';
```

**Commented again :**

```
/* var page_background_color = 'red'; */
/* var page_background_color
               = 'red'; */
```

Read the [ECMAScript specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.4) for more.